# How to use find command to find all files with extensions from list?

Tags: unix, shell, find

I need to find all image files from directory (gif, png, jpg, jpeg).

```
find /path/to/ -name "*.jpg" > log
```

How to modify this string to find not only .jpg files?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

```
find /path/to -regex ".*\.\(jpg\|gif\|png\|jpeg\)" > log
```

Comment: Does not work for me on mac, but works with the -E (extended) option (maybe the pipe is an extended feature?): 

find -E /path/to -iregex ".*\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg)" > log

Answer (score 150):

```
find /path/to/  \( -iname '*.gif' -o -iname '*.jpg' \) -print0
```

will work. There might be a more elegant way.

Comment: -iname would be case insensitive

Comment: @Gerald: It's likely you need to group your OR expression in escaped parentheses: `find /path/to/ \( -iname '*.gif' -o -iname '*.jpg' \) -exec ls -l {} \;` otherwise the exec only applies to the last part (`-iname '*.jpg' ` in this case).

Comment: That's an important remark. `find /path/to/ -iname '*.gif' -o -iname '*.jpg' -print0` will only print the jpg files! You need brackets here: `find /path/to/ \( -iname '*.gif' -o -iname '*.jpg' \) -print0`

Answer (score 36):

`find -E /path/to -regex ".*\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg)" > log`

The `-E` saves you from having to escape the parens and pipes in your regex.

Comment: my find doesn't have this -E

Comment: Hmmm the `-E` option tells `find` to use "extended regular expressions". Several other tools have a similar option, but I'm not sure this option is available on all UNIX distributions.

Comment: Works on Mac OS, too.

Comment: @tboyce12 Working on ubuntu, I can specify the -regextype to simplify the regex expression: `find . -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg)"`.

Comment: How do I edit that regex so that it is not case-sensitive (a.k.a. will match files that end in `.JPG` rather just `.jpg`)?

Comment: @cjm Maybe `find -E /path/to -iregex ".*\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg)" > log`. Using the `-iregex` flag tells `find` to match case insensitively.

Answer (score 13):

```
find /path/to/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file | grep -i image
```

This uses the `file` command to try to recognize the type of file, regardless of filename (or extension).

If `/path/to` or a filename contains the string `image`, then the above may return bogus hits. In that case, I'd suggest

```
cd /path/to
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file --mime-type | grep -i image/
```

Comment: Sorry, had an errant click there and I apparently can't undo the downvote... :(

Answer (score 10):

```
find /path -type f \( -iname "*.jpg" -o -name "*.jpeg" -o -iname "*gif" \)
```

Comment: Could you explain why you added the (escaped) parentheses around the name/iname parameters?

Comment: Any reason for the inconsistency? `-iname *.jpg`, `-o -name *.jpeg`, `-o -iname *gif` all have a slightly different format.

Comment: if you could at least explain differencies with other answers.

Comment: `-o` - logical OR. Not an inconsistency, just joins together the `-iname` clauses. `-iname "*gif"` would match a filename ending `foogif`, whereas `-iname "*.gif"` would not.

Answer (score 9):

On Mac OS use

```
find -E packages  -regex ".*\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg)"
```

Answer (score 6):

In supplement to @Dennis Williamson 's response above, if you want the same regex to be case-insensitive to the file extensions, use -iregex :

```
find /path/to -iregex ".*\.\(jpg\|gif\|png\|jpeg\)" > log
```

Answer (score 3):

```
find -regex ".*\.\(jpg\|gif\|png\|jpeg\)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `-regextype posix-extended` option *only* worked in my case:

```
sudo find . -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|ttf|woff|svg)" -exec chmod 0640 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

in case files have no extension we can look for file mime type

```
find . -type f -exec file -i {} + | awk -F': +' '{ if ($2 ~ /audio|video|matroska|mpeg/) print $1 }'
```

where (audio|video|matroska|mpeg) are mime types regex

&if you want to delete them:

```
find . -type f -exec file -i {} + | awk -F': +' '{ if ($2 ~ /audio|video|matroska|mpeg/) print $1 }' | while read f ; do
  rm "$f"
done
```

or delete everything else but those extensions:

```
find . -type f -exec file -i {} + | awk -F': +' '{ if ($2 !~ /audio|video|matroska|mpeg/) print $1 }' | while read f ; do
  rm "$f"
done
```

notice the !~ instead of ~