# How to delete all files and folders that are not image in a folder?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, find

Do you know how to delete all files that are not image files (.png, .jpg, etc.) and all folders which does not contain image files?

By command line or shell script, is it possible?

Note: I am using Mac terminal

Comment: You can use find, look at this [post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116389/recursively-delete-all-files-with-a-given-extension) but remember to show what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
true=0
false=1

is_empty()
{
    if [ "$(ls -A $1)" ]; then
        return $false
    fi
    return $true
}

del_img()
{
    local i   
    for i in "$1"/*; do
        # file: not png, jpg and our shell script
        if [ -f "${i}" ] && [[ "${i}" != *.png ]] && [[ "${i}" != *.jpg ]] && [[ "${i}" != *.sh ]]; then
            echo "remove ".$(basename "${i}")
            rm "${i}"            
        fi

        # folder: access inside
        if [ -d "${i}" ]; then            
            del_img "${i}"
        fi

        # folder: remove if empty
        if [ -d "${i}" ] && is_empty "${i}"; then
            echo "remove ".$(basename "${i}")
            rmdir "${i}"
        fi
    done
}

del_img $PWD
```

Answer (score 3):

You can firstly [find all files that are not `.png` or `.jpg`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2622857/1983854) and delete them. Then, loop through all directories and try to remove them all. Only those that are empty will be removed:

```
find -type f ! -regex ".*\.\(jpg\|png\)" -delete
find -type d -delete
```

On Mac OS X, [you can't use \| in a basic regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5905513/1983854), which is what `find` uses by default. So if the first expression does not work to you, [use the `-o` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5905538/1983854):

```
find . -type f ! \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.png" \) -delete
```

---

Given this structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── a1
│   └── a.png
├── a2
│   ├── b.jpg
│   └── b.png
└── a3
    ├── a.txt
    └── b.txt

3 directories, 5 files
```

There are the files to remove:

```
$ find -type f ! -regex ".*\.\(jpg\|png\)"
./a3/b.txt
./a3/a.txt
```

So let's do it:

```
$ find -type f ! -regex ".*\.\(jpg\|png\)" -delete
```

And now let's remove dirs:

```
$ find -type d -delete
find: cannot delete `./a1': Directory not empty
find: cannot delete `./a2': Directory not empty
```

So we end up having:

```
$ tree
.
├── a1
│   └── a.png
└── a2
    ├── b.jpg
    └── b.png

2 directories, 3 files
```

Comment: it would be better to use file magic to work out if it is a graphic file

Comment: @Vorsprung interesting. Some kind of `file -ib <file>` and if the output contains `image`.

Comment: find . -type f ! -regex ".*\.\(jpg\|png\)" -delete  ----> it deletes all files

Comment: @chipbk10 it might be that you need the -E flag --> `find -E -type f ! -regex ".*\.\(jpg\|png\)"`. Test it and if it shows what is needed, then add the `-delete`.

Comment: No, it's not working. -E unknown primary or operator

Comment: @chipbk10 Then you probably need `find . -type f ! \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.png" \)`.

Comment: I wrote my own script to achieve my purpose. thanks for your help