# Unix command to search particular type of files in a directory

Tags: unix

How to search particular types of files like *.java,.class* in a specific directory using unix command? I want list of all .java files in a directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use find command to find all files with extensions from list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621513/how-to-use-find-command-to-find-all-files-with-extensions-from-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find /path/to/directory/ -name "*.java" -print
```

This will list all the files ending .java from the specified path